# Picard group of normalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, picard-group, normalization

Let $X$ be a projective variety with at worst (analytic) normal crossings singularities and $\pi:\tilde{X} \to X$ be the normalisation. Is there a "nice" description relating the picard group of $X$ and $\tilde{X}$, for example through a short exact sequence. We know that, in the case $X$ is a curve we have such a short exact sequence.

Any idea/reference will be most helpful.

Comment: Since $X$ is $S2$, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X^\times$ equals the pushforward of $\mathcal{O}_U^\times$ for every open subset $U$ of $X$ whose complement has codimension $2$.  Thus, you can use the same short exact sequence as in the case of a nodal curve to compute the relation between the Picard group of $X$ and the Picard group of $\widetilde{X}$ via the restrictions to the "double locus" in each of $X$ and $\widetilde{X}$.

Comment: I believe my previous comment is wrong.  It is true that rational sections of an invertible sheaf on $X$ that are regular away from codimension $\geq 2$ are everywhere regular.  However, that is not enough to extend invertible sheaves.  By Grothendieck's proof of Samuel's conjecture, if the complement of $U$ has codimension $\geq 4$, then every invertible sheaf on $U$ extends uniquely to $X$.  However, I do not see at the moment whether this holds if the codimension of $U$ equals $2$, resp. $3$.

Comment: If $X$ is the push out of the maps $D\leftarrow \overline{D}\to \overline{X}$ where $D\subset X$ and $\overline{D}\subset\overline{X}$ are the conductor loci, e.g., if $X$ is demi-normal, then you can use Milnor pasting to show that $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is the fibre product of $\mathrm{Pic}(\overline{X})$ and $\mathrm{Pic}(D)$ over $\mathrm{Pic}(\overline{D})$. This is usually very useful. For certain surfaces, there is an exact sequence in an article by Hartshorne and Polini, if I recall correctly.